# Performance Issues with 500x500 Maps in Flame: Tiled Loading Impact on FPS?

Tags: performance, optimization, maps, tiled, flame

I'm uncertain if Flame continuously updates all tiles or if it selectively loads only the visible ones on the screen. The concern arises from my experience with a 500x500 map, which, despite using Tiled loading, results in a significant drop in FPS to around 10. This discrepancy prompts me to question whether Flame's loading mechanism effectively manages performance and optimizes rendering for visible tiles.

I attempted to load a 500x500 map using Flame and experimented with Tiled loading. I anticipated smooth performance, expecting Flame to efficiently handle the map. However, the result was a significant drop in FPS to around 10, prompting concerns about the feasibility of using such a large map with Flame.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no render culling done yet in flame_tiled (or in Flame at all) which is why you are experiencing performance issues with such a large map.

For normal Flame components one can use `CameraComponent.canSee(component)` to implement render culling manually, but since the map is just one big component that wouldn't work here. I don't think it would be possible to do it in flame_tiled manually without doing it inside of the library, if you are up for implementing such a feature we are of course open to PRs.

Another thing you could try is to split up your map into several `TiledComponent`s and then only render the visible ones.